# How to create a button in Custom panel to take you to the specified url

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I am having trouble creating a button on a custom panel, which on clicking will open the browser and take the user to the specified url. Can anyone help me with the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see the docs for [bpy.ops.wm.url_open](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=url#bpy.ops.wm.url_open)

`bpy.ops.wm.url_open(url="")`

so a button would be

```
row.operator('wm.url_open', text='open url').url='http://www.blender.org'
```