# How to put a button on the N panel for URL?

Tags: python, interface

I am looking to place a button in it's own category inside the N panel on the UI. I read this as a reference:
[How to create a button in Custom panel to take you to the specified url](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38944/how-to-create-a-button-in-custom-panel-to-take-you-to-the-specified-url)

This operator is needed:
`row.operator('wm.url_open', text='open url').url='http://www.blender.org'`

I am following PANEL3 from this page example: (the panel in UI, VIEW): https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/creating-panels-for-placing-blender-add-ons-user-interface-ui/

My code looks like (taken from ui_panel_simple.py template).

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

But I get an error on:
`def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)`

I would like a button that I can click to a URL from the N panel in Blender 2.81.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is re registering... remove  `bl_context` since it is not required outside 'PROPERTIES' area.  Please in future paste the error message from the system console into your question.

Anyway here is a suggested edit.  Please take note of the class names. and registration code. If another class that needs registering, eg panel of operator, simply pop in the class and add to `classes` tuple.

Adds a Quick Links panel to 3d view UI "N" panel under the category "Links".

```
import bpy

links = {"Blender" : 'http://www.blender.org',
         "BSE" : "https://blender.stackexchange.com",
         }


class VIEW3D_PT_links(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Quick Links"""
    bl_label = "Quick Links"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_links"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = 'Links'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        for name, url in links.items():
            op = col.operator('wm.url_open', text=name)
            op.url = url

classes = (
        VIEW3D_PT_links,
        )

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

edit: added links dictionary to add more links simply.

Comment: Can't I give you some of the coins I have? This code is gold! Thank you sir! works perfectly!

Comment: What if these 2 buttons were to be included in a custom property of an object's panel?